# How do variables exported in `/etc/profile.d` end up in the systemd user environment on Gnome?

Tags: gnome, environment-variables, gdm, systemd-user

On Gnome with Systemd, systemd user environment variables are configured using the [systemd environment.d](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-environment-d-generator.html#) mechanism, which doesn't rely on shell scripts, but on configuration files.
In parallel, many environment variables are defined in the Gnome session using exports in scripts in `/etc/profile.d/*`.

These two systems (the environment.d configuration files and the scripts in `/etc/profile.d/*`) are not permeable (even if there are ways to manually import these variables, like `systemctl --user import-environment`)

Moreover, when using Wayland, there is no sourcing of the `/etc/profile.d/*` scripts as it is done in Gnome on Xorg (using the `/etc/gdm/Xsession` script, which itself sources `/etc/profile` which itself sources the `/etc/profile.d/*` and `~/.profile` scripts).

So the variables exported in these `/etc/profile.d/*` shouldn't appear in the systemd user environment when using Gnome, neither in Xorg, and a fortiori neither with Wayland.

However, this is not the case.
For example, the `/etc/profile.d/google-cloud-sdk.sh` script exports some custom variables:

```
export CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR=/opt/google-cloud-sdk
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_ARGS=-S
export PATH=$CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR/bin:$PATH
export GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK_HOME=$CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR
```

And after logging in on Gnome on Wayland and on Xorg, we run `systemctl --user show-environment`

And we see the exact same variables:

```
...
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
CLOUDSDK_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_ARGS=-S
CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR=/opt/google-cloud-sdk
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
...
GOOGLE_CLOUD_SDK_HOME=$CLOUDSDK_ROOT_DIR
...
```

Among many other variables.

Two additional remarks:

- variables exported in `~/.profile` are not seen in the systemd user environments, which would imply that the `/etc/profile` script is itself not sourced: the `/etc/profile.d/*` scripts seem to be sourced directly
- There is no reference to any `/etc/profile.d/*` script in the [systemd environment generators](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.environment-generator.html#)

So, how is this possible, considering the fact there is no documented way for systemd or gnome to source these `/etc/profile.d/*` scripts?